# Copy and past a app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I finished a "base app" for all my next apps in eclipse, with admob, contact us...

Can i sort of import this project in a new app and work from there? Or just copy and paste everything and just change the name? How? Like just start a new app with every thing like that app and the work it out from there?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn your base app into a Library project (see http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/03/03/android-library-projects/) and your other apps will include this library.

One gotcha with this is that the AndroidManifest.xml from your library is ignored, so you may need to manually copy activities, services, etc. from your library manifest to the real manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I would put my "base app" project in a code repository (git in my case), and then just clone it, change the output name, libs etc in any build scripts. Check that into a new repository and keep working from there.

If you don't use git/svn/whatever just copy your source files and create a new project in eclipse, it's probably easier and less error prone than copying the project files as well and trying to remember all the places that refer to your old project.

Might be a little off-topic but what I usually do is I have pure source (and some build scripts) in a code repository and then outside that (in my eclipse workspace) I create the eclipse project and link the source files into my project. So if I trigger builds with eclipse I get the build output in my project directory while keeping my source directory clean.